# Ubuntu 14.10 mouse doesn't move without a click

Tags: mouse, 14.10

I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10 yesterday. A strange thing happens: if I want to move my mouse, I need to click it first, and when I leave it there and want to use it later, I need to click again!

Could you guys help me?

Comment: Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a wireless mouse?  If so check the owner's manual-- the mouse probably has a time-activated power-save mode that switches it off to save battery, and the only way to reactivate the mouse its to click one of the buttons.